# Trigger with aspnet_Users table

Tags: asp.net

Peace be upon you

I've created a trigger on the aspnet_Users that is provided by ASPNETDB in Visual Studio 2008.

```
ALTER TRIGGER UpdateTrigger
ON dbo.aspnet_Users
FOR UPDATE 
AS 

declare @InHisAccount decimal(18,0); 

IF UPDATE( PreCardNo )
set @InHisAccount = 15000;

insert into dbo.aspnet_Users(InHisAccount) values (@InHisAccount);
```

When I'm trying to login into the site after creating the trigger on the aspnet_Users, I can't and give the message that tells me there is an error in logining, although that the username and password are true, and when I delete the trigger, logining returning back to works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use an AFTER UPDATE trigger so the normal ASPNETDB call can commit.

Comment: I've used 'AFTER UPDATE', and I Get this message when I'm trying to build the solution, Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ApplicationId', table 'D:\USERS\BASSEM\DESKTOP\MINIMALL\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF.dbo.aspnet_Users'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.